# MySQL After Update Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm working in MySQL after using SQL Plus and am trying to create an after update trigger. I've tried doing a few variants, but I keep getting syntax errors. Would you be able to tell me where I'm going wrong? Much Thanks.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_user_update 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON user_list FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  UPDATE ON account
  SET ACTION = 'update',
  user_name = new.user_name;
END;
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: That doesn't look like any valid UPDATE statement I've ever seen in MySQL.

Comment: The error message (1064)  says I should check the syntax to use near 'END' at line 1, but nothing I do seems to resolve it.

Comment: @Uueerdo what would you recommend?

Comment: My best guess would be the answer juergen d provided; his addition of delimiter statements probably addresses your specific error, and his UPDATE is as close as I could guess to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER after_user_update AFTER UPDATE ON user_list 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  UPDATE account
  SET ACTION = 'update'
  WHERE user_name = new.user_name;
END //
delimiter ;
```

There were a few issues here. You should use a SQL IDE like *MySQL Workbench* to highlight the errors. And you need to change the delimiter first.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I tried using delimiter earlier, but perhaps I was doing it incorrectly. I was using delimiter $$

Comment: It does not matter which delimiter you define. You just have to change the default  `;` into something else. Otherwise the trigger definition ends at the first `;` which would make it incomplete

Answer (score -2):

You may try this code.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_user_update 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON user_list FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  UPDATE ON account
  SET ACTION = 'update',
  user_name = new.user_name;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```